# Terraform - Create or not create resources based on conditions

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I need my resources to be created on specified environments. For example, if I have a AWS Lambda that is not ready for production, I need it to only exist in development environment. Is there a nice way to do this? I know that it's possible to set `count` to 0, but I'm not sure how to cascade this decision to other resources.

For example, I have a resource for an AWS Lambda and the `count` is set to 0.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "example_lambda" {
  count ? local.is_production ? 0 : 1
}
```

How do I cascade this decision to other resources that depends on the AWS Lambda above?

And let's say I have a S3 Bucket which will invoke the Lambda function.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example_bucket" {
  bucket = "bucket_name"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "example_bucket_etl" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromS3Bucket"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.example_lambda.arn
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_s3_bucket.example_bucket.arn
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example_bucket.id

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.example_lambda.arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "example_bucket/"
    filter_suffix       = ".txt"
  
  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.another_lambda_function.arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]    
    filter_prefix       = "another_example_bucket/"
    filter_suffix       = ".txt"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same count variable on multiple resources. A nicer and clear way would be to add all resources into a module, if that is possible in your code. https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html

Comment: Let me look into it. Thanks @TobiasBruckert. Unfortunately, I wont be able to set the resources into different modules. At least, not now.

Comment: Yes maybe not all but at least the lambda and the s3 notification.

Comment: I may use dynamic blocks for the nested contents. Not the best solution, but it will help me for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `count` in a `resource` block, that makes Terraform treat references to that resource elsewhere as producing a list of objects representing each of the instances of that resource.

Since that value is just a normal list value, you can take its length in order to concisely write down what is essentially the statement "there should be one Y for each X", or in your specific case "there should be one lambda permission for each lambda function".

For example:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "example" {
  count = local.is_production ? 0 : 1

  # ...
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "example_bucket_etl" {
  count = length(aws_lambda_function.example)

  function_name = aws_lambda_function.example[count.index].name
  # ...
}
```

Inside the `aws_lambda_permission` configuration we first set the count to be whatever is the count of the `aws_lambda_function.example`, which tells Terraform that we intend for the counts of these to always match. That connection helps Terraform understand how to resolve situations where you increase or reduce the count, by hinting that the resulting create/destroy actions will need to happen in a particular order in order to be valid. We then use `count.index` to refer to indices of the other resource, which in this case will only ever be zero but again helps Terraform understand our intent during validation.

The `lambda_function` nested block inside `aws_s3_bucket_notification` requires a slightly different strategy, since in that case we're not creating a separate resource instance per lambda function but instead just generating some dynamic configuration blocks inside a single resource instance. For that situation, we can use [`dynamic` blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) which serve as a sort of macro for generating multiple blocks based on elements of a collection:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example_bucket.id

  dynamic "lambda_function" {
    for_each = aws_lambda_function.example
    content {
      # "lambda_function" in this block is the iterator
      # symbol, so lambda_function.value refers to the
      # current element of aws_lambda_function.example.
      lambda_function_arn = lambda_function.value.arn
      # ...
    }
  }
}
```

Again this is relying on the fact that `aws_lambda_function.example` is a list of objects, but in a different way: we ask Terraform to generate a `lambda_function` block for each element of `aws_lambda_function.example`, setting `lambda_function.value` to the whole `aws_lambda_function` object corresponding to each block. We can therefore access the `.arn` attribute from that object to get the corresponding ARN that we need to populate the `lambda_function_arn` argument inside the block.

Again, for this case there will only ever be zero or one lambda function objects and therefore only zero or one `lambda_function` blocks, but in both cases this pattern generalizes to other values of `count`, ensuring that all of these will stay aligned as your configuration evolves.